# Trouble understanding Big O notation for a sum of n integers

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

This problem is an example in a Discrete Math textbook. How can big-O notation be used to estimate the sum of the first n positive integers?

Solution: Because each of the integers in the sum of the first n positive integers does not exceed n, it follows that
$$1+2+...+n \le n+n+...+n=n^2$$
From this inequality it follows that $1+2+...+n$ is $O(n^2)$.

I do not understand how the sum of $n$'s is equal to $n^2$. Can anyone explain to me what the book used to get this?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you'd want to estimate the sum of the first n positive integers since this is a well-known formula $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: How many "$n$"s are in the sum "$n+n+\cdots+n$"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of $n$ $n$'s is $n \cdot n$, by definition. $n \cdot n = n^2$.

Also, Big-O notation is used for *bounding*, not estimation. As Big-O notation removes all constant multipliers and merely represents an *upper asymptotic bound*, it is not a useful estimator.

Comment: Maybe "\cdot" ?

Comment: Done. I am always too lazy to make that switch in my homework, but it's probably a bad habit I should break out of.

Comment: Thank you! This was an example problem in Rosen's Discrete Math book. I didn't really understand the purpose of the example but just needed to clarify that one step.

Comment: @user2258552 "Big-O notation removes all constant multipliers" was the key to understand this, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

First, you note that$$1+2+\ldots+n = \frac{n^2+n}{2} $$
Since this is a quadratic polynomial, follows that it is $O(n^2)$.